# Upgrading windows 2003 to windows 2008 in MOSS 2007 Farm

Tags: upgrade, infrastructure, windows-server

have MOSS 2007 SP2 installed in windows 2003 SP2 32bit and need to uprade the windows 2003 SP2 to windows 2008 SP2 in existing environment.  I am not sure whether operating system can be upgraded in MOSS 2007 farm.I have googled and found that [it can be upgraded on WSS 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288690%28office.12%29.aspx) but not found anything about MOSS 2007 OS upgrade.

1. Can I do inplace upgrade of Windows 2003 to windows 2008 directly in already running MOSS 2007 farm without having any issues or do i need to do clean installation and then migrate data?
2. What is the best approach to upgrade Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 in already running MOSS 2007 farm?
3. Does Microsoft supports the inplace upgrade of Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 in already running MOSS 2007 farm?

Comment: This is not a development question, but the experts on SharePoint StackExchange would be happy to answer this kind of question.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but it would be helpful for future upgrades (SharePoint 2010) to upgrade to x64 bit version of Windows 2008 if possible.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Server is built on top of WSS.  AS long as your are doing a x86 to x86 upgrade you should be ok following the Technet article.

However, if you move to R2 that is x64 only and it requires a clean install.

Clean installs are preferred in almost every instance, as they usually will give you less headaches.